# In C can a long printf statement be broken up into multiple lines?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following statement:

```
printf("name: %s\targs: %s\tvalue %d\tarraysize %d\n", sp->name, sp->args, sp->value, sp->arraysize);
```

I want to break it up.  I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
printf("name: %s\t
args: %s\t
value %d\t
arraysize %d\n", 
sp->name, 
sp->args, 
sp->value, 
sp->arraysize);
```

How can I break it up?

Comment: Some good suggestions given, but neither of them may be as clear or maintainable as just four separate printf() calls.

Comment: @Clifford: then you could write C++ so cout looks better for you.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

If you want to break a string literal onto multiple lines, you can concatenate multiple strings together, one on each line, like so:

```
printf("name: %s\t"
"args: %s\t"
"value %d\t"
"arraysize %d\n", 
sp->name, 
sp->args, 
sp->value, 
sp->arraysize);
```

Comment: just commenting to explain the little-known C fact that whitespace between two strings is concatenation.

Comment: @Lundin Having each variable and its value clearly represented on its own line is much easier to read for me. Can you imagine a debugger in an IDE that put all variables and values onto a single line? I can't. _(Yes, I know it doesn't put new-line characters between each string, but I'm comparing the readibility of the source code to the readibility of variables in a debugger)_

Comment: Is this concatenation made by the preprocessor?

Answer (score 37):

The C compiler can glue adjacent string literals into one, like

```
printf("foo: %s "
       "bar: %d", foo, bar);
```

The preprocessor can use a backslash as a last character of the line, not counting CR (or CR/LF, if you are from Windowsland):

```
printf("foo %s \
bar: %d", foo, bar);
```

Comment: The first has already been suggested, the second suffers from the fact that it breaks if there is any whitespace *after* the '\'; a bug that can be baffling when it occurs.

Comment: Neither of those two examples have anything at all to do with the C preprocessor.

Comment: @Dan my cpp seems to understand / (see my edit above).  I'm not sure if this is standard behavior.

Comment: @Dan While joining adjacent literals may be performed with either preprocessor or compiler (at it last stage before actual compilation), handling line continuation is performed by preprocessor, because otherwise multiline macros cannot be implemented. Also see here - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html

Comment: @sigjuice It is a standard behaviour so your edit is superfluous

Comment: @qrdl: My bad, you are right about the second one. Line continuation is always done by the preprocessor. Sometimes I need to be reminded that I'm *not* a know-it-all ;)  I do still think that in the normal case the compiler joins string literals, though.

Comment: @qrdl That edit was more of a discussion of one of the points raised by @Dan.

Answer (score 23):

Just some other formatting options:

```
printf("name: %s\targs: %s\tvalue %d\tarraysize %d\n", 
        a,        b,        c,        d);

printf("name: %s\targs: %s\tvalue %d\tarraysize %d\n", 
              a,        b,        c,            d);

printf("name: %s\t"      "args: %s\t"      "value %d\t"      "arraysize %d\n", 
        very_long_name_a, very_long_name_b, very_long_name_c, very_long_name_d);
```

You can add variations on the theme. The idea is that the `printf()` conversion speficiers and the respective variables are all lined up "nicely" (for some values of "nicely").

Comment: Nothing functional here, but a novel idea I've never seen before. I like it, great comment @pmg!

Answer (score 6):

The de-facto standard way to split up complex functions in C is per argument:

```
printf("name: %s\targs: %s\tvalue %d\tarraysize %d\n", 
       sp->name, 
       sp->args, 
       sp->value, 
       sp->arraysize);
```

Or if you will:

```
const char format_str[] = "name: %s\targs: %s\tvalue %d\tarraysize %d\n";
...
printf(format_str, 
       sp->name, 
       sp->args, 
       sp->value, 
       sp->arraysize);
```

You shouldn't split up the string, nor should you use `\` to break a C line. Such code quickly turns completely unreadable/unmaintainable.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think using one `printf` statement to print string literals as seen above is a good programming practice; rather, one can use the piece of code below:

```
printf("name: %s\t",sp->name);
printf("args: %s\t",sp->args);
printf("value: %s\t",sp->value);
printf("arraysize: %s\t",sp->name);
```