# How can I format string concatenations ("abc" + "def") as I format paragraph in Vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have this piece of code

```
var t = "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc " +
        "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc";
```

I edit the first line but it exceeds the 80 columns in my editor

```
var t = "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc ABC ABC ABC abc" +
        "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc";
```

I don't like to have this in my code, so I need to format all lines

```
var t = "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc " +
        "ABC ABC ABC abc abc abc abc abc abc " +
        "abc abc abc abc";
```

There is possible to solve this using something like `gq}` or do you know a plugin that could help me?

Comment: Vim can format and merge comment lines (option set fo=j), but i don't think it can do this with multiline strings.

Comment: Are you working on a terminal from the 80's?

Comment: Similar question, also unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15757298

Answer (score 0):

Until you find a plugin, you could record a macro `qq`, go to the right 80 times `80l`, go to the end of the word before `ge`, append `a` `" + <ENTER> "<Esc>`, save the macro `q`.

Then you would join the following lines with `J` and delete unwanted `" + "` patterns.

You can play the macro again with `@q`.