# C: trying to split fprintf() format string into multiple lines with line-continuation using \ adds tabs at the beginning of lines that follow

Tags: c, gcc, vim, printf, line-continuation

I am trying to split a long `format string` to `fprintf()` into multiple lines using the `\` character as shown below:

```
fprintf(stdout, "This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...\n\
                        And returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.\n\n\
                        Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: ");
```

this causes `whitespaces` to be added to the output as shown below:

```
This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...
                        And returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.

                        Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format:
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797351/14381272) answer suggests this should work. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752401/14381272) answer before posting here. A comment on it mentions that this approach...

> ...suffers from the fact that it breaks if there is any whitespace after
> the '\'; a bug that can be baffling when it occurs.

`cat -A`'s output on the program file...

```
^Ifprintf(stdout, "This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...\n\$
^I^I^IAnd returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.\n\n\$
^I^I^IEnter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: ");$
```

...shows no whitespace after `\`; although it does introduce `<TAB>`s into the lines that follow. I am using `vim` to edit my source files.

I use line continuation with `\` all the time in `Bash`, and was under the impression that it works similarly with `fprintf()` format strings in C.

I'd like to keep my code readable and line widths reasonable. Other than splitting the long string into multiple `fprintf()`.

1. **Is this standard behavior for `printf()/fprintf()`**
2. **Is it normal for a `vim` to my code when I do line continuation with `\`?**
3. **How do I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `\` as it is not a macro definition.

Simply have as many as you want as string literals separated by as many as you want whitespace (new line is also a whitespace). The C compiler ignores the whitespace.

```
int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...\n"
                    "And returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.\n\n"
                    "Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: ");
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "This program take a date"
                    " supplied by the user in dd/"
                    "mm/yyyy format...\n"
                    "And returns "
                    "the "
                    "day of "
                    "the "
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    "week for that "
                    "date using Zeller's rule.\n\n"
                    "Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: ");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6ovj3G

Answer (score 2):

There are fairly low limits in actual portability, but practically you can almost certainly do:

```
fprintf(stdout, "This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...\n"
        "And returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.\n\n"
        "Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: "
);
```

If you do start hitting limits on concatenating strings like that, you can also do:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n%s\n\n%s",
        "This program take a date supplied by the user in dd/mm/yyyy format...",
        "And returns the day of the week for that date using Zeller's rule.",
        "Enter date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format: "
);
```

Comment: could you please explain what you meant by "fairly low limits in actual portability". Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @anitesh — I'd guess that the concern is that pre-standard C compilers did not support string literal concatenation.  It is unlikely to be a practical problem except perhaps in obscure embedded systems.

Comment: I remember with the last decade using a compiler that had a limit on the length of a string literal that was less than 1K.  I don't suppose any reasonable modern implementation will have a limit so low that the above strings won't work.